# Node.js as webserver with MySQL

Tags: mysql, linux, node.js

I am looking to create a webserver, with the lightest possible setup.  Is it possible to run a webserver with node.js, MySQL on a 512MB RAM server.

Comment: Minus the linode.js the mysql is same as on a LAMP?

Comment: @LinusGThiel Will the server be more than 50% faster than Apache?

Comment: Searched the net, but did not find any good docs?

Comment: More information http://nodeguide.com/beginner.html

Comment: @Jean: Re "50% faster" - That's an impossible question to answer. I suggest you use tools you are familiar with when building something, and use tools you are interested in when experimenting.

Answer (score 4):

you can hit

> $ npm install mysql

and then include

```
var _mysql = require('mysql');

var HOST = 'localhost';
var PORT = 3306;
var MYSQL_USER = 'nodehacker';
var MYSQL_PASS = 'lulwut';
var DATABASE = 'nodedb';
var TABLE = 'gadgets';

var mysql = _mysql.createClient({
    host: HOST,
    port: PORT,
    user: MYSQL_USER,
    password: MYSQL_PASS,
});

mysql.query('use ' + DATABASE);
```